# adding a attributes to a custom html helper for drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, extension-methods

I have implemented the solution here:
http://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/ASP-NET-MVC-DropDownListFor-Html-Helper-Enum-5

It simply creates a dropdown list from member of enums. However, I want to associate a name with the dropdown list like here:

`@Html.TextBox("username", Model.Username, new { id = "username" })`

To illustrate, I want to use it in such a way:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FavoriteColor, new { id = "username" } )`

How can I do that? How can I expand the Extention method of the EnumEditorHtmlHelper class?

Here is the definition of EnumEditorHtmlHelper:

```
namespace LojmanMVC.WebUI.Static
{
public static class EnumEditorHtmlHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the DropDown List (HTML Select Element) from LINQ 
    /// Expression where the expression returns an Enum type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">The type of the property.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper">The HTML helper.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">The expression.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString MyEnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        where TModel : class
    {
        TProperty value = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model == null 
            ? default(TProperty)
            : expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        string selected = value == null ? String.Empty : value.ToString();
        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, createSelectList(expression.ReturnType, selected));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the select list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enumType">Type of the enum.</param>
    /// <param name="selectedItem">The selected item.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> createSelectList(Type enumType, string selectedItem)
    {
        return (from object item in Enum.GetValues(enumType)
                let fi = enumType.GetField(item.ToString())
                let attribute = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault()
                let title = attribute == null ? item.ToString() : ((DescriptionAttribute)attribute).Description
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = item.ToString(),
                    Text = title,
                    Selected = selectedItem == item.ToString()
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using same method but it need `second parameter` to be a `collection` of `SelectListItems` and `third parameter` is for your `custom` attributes.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FavoriteColor, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Colors, new {id="username" })
```

Comment: It is clear that I shall add another parameter to the helper method, however, I  shall make necessary changes in EnumEditorHtmlHelper class.

Comment: is this your custom class ?